# Content overflow inside div

Tags: html, css, laravel

I have a patient history form in my Laravel project. My content overflow under a div like below image.

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qPzs.jpg)

I have used `overflow:hidden` in css part. Then my content disappear like below image.

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yKED.jpg)

**Here is the html code**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2"><b> Chief Complains : </b></div>
   <div class="col-md-10"> {!! $data[0]->chief_complaints !!} </div>
</div>
```

How to solve this ? Anybody help please ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `overflow:scroll` if you want it scrollable. otherwise, shrink the div width.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people can assist you in finding the error

Comment: @ChristopherBennett...no I don't want scrollable...Anything else brother ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your div a CSS property like below

```
.your-div-class {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Add width to the upper container so this will work.

Comment: Add specific width to the parent div so the child div will get 100% width of parent

Comment: Try this .yourdivclass { overflow-wrap: break-word; }

Comment: I think this will help you some how : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/

Answer (score 0):

set your paragraph or content to

```
overflow:scroll;
```

or

set `width:to some value less than the container width`